# Return meta arrays foreach post and merge into one

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Custom Post Type called Boutique with a repeater field called Products.

My loop is working but i want all products to display in random order.

Exemple :

Boutique A with products : [1,2,3]
Boutique B with products : [4,5,6]

I would like an array like this : array( [1],[4],[2],[3],[5],[6] )

Actually i can only get this with a shuffle : array( [4,5,6],[1,2,3] )

How should i merge all products into one single array so then i can shuffle and do the loop?

```
$boutiques = get_posts(array(
    'fields'          => 'ids',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'post_type' => 'boutique'
));
shuffle($boutiques);

 foreach ( $boutiques as $boutique_id ) {

          if( have_rows('boutique_products', $boutique_id) ):
      while  ( have_rows('boutique_products', $boutique_id) ): 
        the_row(); ?>

        <div class="boutique_product">
          <a href="<?php 
   echo esc_url( $boutique_url ); ?>">
            <img src="<?php 
   the_sub_field('product_img'); ?>">
          </a>
        </div>

      <?php  
   endwhile; else :
  endif; ?>
```

Comment: Use `array_merge` before the shuffle.

Comment: @Dave if i do that, i will have my "boutique_id" merged together, but the products won't be shuffled. So the problem will be the same. I need in some way, to get all products in an array and then shuffle them.